# Updating my Column in SQLite with Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a method in my activity class which should print a random role to the player (stores in an SQLite database). I am getting a success message but it is not being carried out. I only have 1 record in my SQLite database so far and will be adding a while loop after to populate each row.

This is my my activity class:

```
public class StartGame extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        DatabaseHelper myDb;
        Button btnRoles;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_startgame);
            myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

            btnRoles = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAssignRoles);
            assignRoles();
        }

        public String RandomNumber() {
            List < String > roles = Arrays.asList("Mafia", "Mafia", "Angel", "Detective", "Civilian", "Civilian", "Civilian");
            Collections.shuffle(roles);
            return roles.get(0);
        }
        public void assignRoles() {

            btnRoles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        {
                            boolean isUpdated = myDb.updateRole(RandomNumber().toString());
                            if (isUpdated == true)
                                Toast.makeText(StartGame.this, "Roles assigned, keep them secret!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(StartGame.this, "UNSUCCESSFUL!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
```

And this is the method in my Database Helper class:

```
public boolean updateRole(String role){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_ROLE, role);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "Role =?", new String[] {role});
    return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it mean that you have one role stored at anytime in the database and you update this single role from the random string?

Comment: Why does `updateRole()` always return **true**? It should read `return db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "Role =?", new String[] {role}) > 0;`, instead.

Comment: @Inducesmile No, I want all the roles to be taken and each player to have their own roles.

Comment: @Rotwang my bad, I have changed that and it now says it is Unsuccessful.

Comment: OK, now try the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got an error in this line:

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "Role =?", new String[] {role});
```

You are updating all the rows in the table where `Role = {role}` to have the column `Role` the value `{role}`. So obviously this will have no effect.

You need to have some thing like `id` and use that in your where statement, some thing like this:

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "id =?", new String[] {id});
```

Comment: Would I need to change both parameters to id? Would it still update my "role" column? How would this work? Thanks :)

Comment: Unless you enter the where condition it will update all your rows, so you need some how to tell it what row to update, so in addition to Role, I would also ad an id. Here is an example to how it can work: update Role to be "cool" where id = 122. Or in other words find row with id = 122 and set its Role to be "cool".